# Magento 2.0.9 stock does not decrease with order / stock levels do not update

Tags: magento2, upgrade, stock

We have recently installed Magento 2 on AWS, after using Magento 1 on another server. We did a fresh install with a new store. Magento is up to date at 2.0.9. Everything is running, except when an order is placed, stock does not decrease. 
**Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Decrease Stock When Order is Placed** is set to **Yes**.

I have searched extensively on this issue and have found nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated - we are close to launch and have only just noticed this issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.1 has the same issue when it was updated from 2.0.2. New products worked fine, but ones that were there before the update did not decrease in stock. They increased in stock if an order was canceled though. I ended up having to open each product and hit save.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Indeed canceling orders increases the stock, thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately the problem persists for both newly created products and after hitting save on current products. Any further input would be much appreciated - in the meantime I might try upgrading to 2.1.

Comment: Any update on the fix or the solution...Or is this the bug in magento 2? Im using Magento 2.2.0

Comment: Are you using a development version? Magento 2.2 isn't out yet.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5945) and [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5222) the issue on github and how to fix it. Hope it helps.